# How to pass the jquery hidden value to php

Tags: php, html, ajax, jquery

in my code i am creating a drop down box and storing the changed value of the drop down in hidden variable.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>

  div { color:red; }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <select id="sweets">
    <option>Chocolate</option>
    <option selected="selected">Candy</option>

    <option>Taffy</option>
    <option selected="selected">Caramel</option>
    <option>Fudge</option>
    <option>Cookie</option>

  </select>
  <input type="hidden" id="inputfield">
  <div></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#sweets").change(function() {
    var var_name = $(this).val();
    $('input[id=inputfield]').val(theValue);
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>


<?php

if(isset($_POST['form']))
echo $_POST['inputfield'];
?>
```

once the combo box is changed the php should get the hidden field value and i ve to perform db transaction. again i need to load another drop down box based on the selected value.. Can you guide me

Comment: You should use Ajax to do this

Answer (score 1):

You can bypass all the horse trading with the hidden field and send it to php directly via ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#sweets").change(function() {
    $.post('myphpfile.php', {sweet : $(this).val() });
  });
});
```

myphpfile.php will receive the value as a post with the name of 'sweet'

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, shouldn't

`$('input[id=inputfield]').val(theValue);`

be

`$('input[id=inputfield]').val(var_name);`

?

Comment: You could also shorten it down to `$('#inputField')`

Comment: Right, but since his is technically correct, I didn't wanna change everything.  It could be shortened even more by removing the variable assignment altogether and putting it in the `.val()`.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the select and hidden elements in form element adding a post method and action attribute. Give the hidden field a name as in name="hidden field"
this way you can access it in the post variable.

```
<form action="currentpage.php" method="post">
 <select id="sweets">
    <option>Chocolate</option>
    <option selected="selected">Candy</option>

    <option>Taffy</option>
    <option selected="selected">Caramel</option>
    <option>Fudge</option>
    <option>Cookie</option>

  </select>
  <input type="hidden" id="inputfield" name="hiddenfield"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

When the change event executes to update the hidden field and you submit in php you can do

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
   $val = $_POST["hiddenfield"] ;
}
```

Comment: I would look at the more elegant solutions posted though.

Comment: i am trying to create a dynamic drop down box.. this will work only after the submit button is clicked.. i want to change the drop down using on change event

Comment: So you want 2 drop downs. Changing dropdownA updates the options in dropdownB?

Comment: Then I would just call the submit method in the change event. Something like document.forms["myform"].submit();
 "myform" would be the Id of the form.